# laravel elasticsearch just search from first model

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, indexing, laravel-scout

I installed the `scout` and then the `Erick Tamayo / laravel-scout-elastic` driver.
I successfully added The first model with this command
`php artisan scout: import model`
and command
`model :: search ('query')`
It also worked properly when I added the second model with the command
`php artisan scout: import newModel`
successful message returned but command
`new model :: search ('query')`
Returns a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm change elasticsearch Driver and problem solved!!